# Alternative method to handle conflict with underscore

Tags: javascript, foreach, underscore.js, lodash

I have a problem when I import my library lodash.js and when I use underscore.
I have seen in other posts, that we can use the method _.noConflict ()

I use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/main.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
            _u = _.noConflict();
</script>
```

However, my project needs to use the library lodash () so this solution does not work.
Is there another solution?

Comment: Why do you need underscore **and** lodash?

Comment: @lexith
Lodash is called several times between libraries. And I use underscore in my functions

Comment: @lexith
Do you know if threre is an other method than _.noConflict() ?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with that. they aren't meant to be used together anyway (they are basically the same thing). You should just switch to using lodash overall instead trying to combine them.